# Creating calculator service with Java Socket and ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I've tried to create a basic server with Java's ServerSocket and Socket clases. The idea is that the client has to send the server a number and an operation, and the server just has to return the result. I've this code so far:

For the client:

```
package clientepm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class Stub {

    Socket s;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    Stub(){
        try {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 50000);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());         
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Stub.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public double calculate(char op, int num){

        try {
            oos.writeChar(op);
            oos.writeInt(num);
            double ret = ois.readDouble();
            s.close();
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            return ret;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Stub.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return -1;

    }

}

package clientepm;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Client extends Thread {

    Stub s;

    Client(Stub s){
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        int[] numbers = {12,23,35,43,55};
        char[] ops = {'M','M','Q','Q','M'};
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            double result = s.calculate(ops[i], numbers[i]);
            System.out.println("Received Value " + result);
        }


    }

}



package clientepm;

public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stub b = new Stub();
        new Client(b).start();
    }

}
```

For the server:

```
package servidorpm;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Skel extends Thread {

    Socket s;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    Skel(Socket s){
        try {
            this.s=s;
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Skel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try {
                char op = ois.readChar();
                int num = ois.readInt();
                switch(op){
                    case 'M':
                        oos.writeDouble(num*10);
                        break;
                    case 'Q':
                        oos.writeDouble(num*num);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Error");
                        break;
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception");
                Logger.getLogger(Skel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    }

}

package servidorpm;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ServerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(50000);
            while (true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept();
                new Skel(s).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see the server is supposed to multiply x10 when the operation is 'M' and to square the number when the operation is 'Q'. However, the code doesn't work...

Could anybody help me?

Comment: can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? do you have an exception?

Comment: The program is just frozen, nothing is printed.